# asp.net free session variables on page change

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, viewstate

I have a web application that use Session variables for mantain the state of some datatable. I'm not using viewstate for not increase weight of the page.

I not need to mantain the state on page changing, so I want free these session variables on page leave.

How can I intercept when user changing website page ? There is a method like "Page Leave"?

Comment: y u want session to store datatable u can keep data in datatable only. y are u adding to session ?

Comment: I need datatable for differet event on same page, example, for gridview order or paging...

Answer (score 7):

Session data is useful for storing data beyond the lifetime of a page. If you don't want to store it beyond the life of a page then Session data is not for you here.

Comment: But session data is often page specific.

Comment: yes, but that does not answer the question, consider the situation when we want to preserve value in a specific page within post backs but then we want to free the session variable once the user leaves the page.

Answer (score 3):

Try this after navigate to page

```
Session.Remove("Name");
```

or to completely remove the session

```
Session.Clear();
or 
Session.Abadon();
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you tu use class base for all pages of your website, and use `PreviousPage` property, who permit you to define your link (state machine diagram)

And you can define Session.Remove for cleaning

Another remark : suggest you to use viewstate because pemit you persist datas without adding code, important to have < 30K for each page. just this

Answer (score 1):

In a web application, there are various ways a user can "leave" a page. The model of a web application is request based; client and server do not know of each other between requests. Some techniques as cookies or session state try to close this gap, but basically there is no connection. 
 
Therefore, the browser will not notify the server if the user leaves a page, so there is no such event as a Page_Leave. However, you could solve this for some cases (e.g. if the user changes to another page of your application), but not for all.

As @Terror.Blade pointed out, session data is for data that needs to be persisted across a single pages lifecycle. Therefore I'd not suggest to put these data into the Session and find a (not very stable) way to delete it once the user leaves the page.
As it seems it is not an option for you to request the DataTable again for the same user (though this is a common way). I can suggest you the following alternatives:

- If the DataTable is not too big, as you know ViewState is an option that asserts that the data is not persisted across the page lifecycle.
- You can also use the [Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsbfdd8c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to store the data. In contrast to Session state, the Cache has capabilities to free the memory after a certain time or if memory is required for more important data. However, be prepared that the data might need to be fetched again if it was removed from the Cache between requests. Also be aware that the cache is shared among all users and not limited to a Session, so you need to make sure that the users do not see information that is not intended for them. This can also be an advantage, if the DataTable is the same for several users, you can store it in the Cache once.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use the `global.asax` file of the web-application and it's `Application_BeginRequest` event:

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext context = base.Context;
        HttpRequest request = context.Request;
        string pageName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(request.RawUrl);
        if (pageName != "YourPageName")
        {
            if(context.Session["NameOfSessionVariable"] != null)
                context.Session.Remove("NameOfSessionVariable");
        }
    }
}
```

However, i would let it die silently when the session exprires.

Comment: @tulkas85: What does that mean?

Comment: If I want to free session on page changing, maybe I do something like this on you code :
if (pageName != HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString())

Comment: @tulkas85: I thought that you need that `DataTable` only at one specific page. So why can't you replace `YourPageName` with this name instead? Your approach would remove this `Session` value on every page change even if the previous page didn't use the `DataTable`.

Comment: I have different datatables in different pages... I want remove all in session except the user logged session information.
so, I think to use your code adding a loop for each object in session except some object...

Comment: Why do you need the tables in the session at all? That'll increase the needed memory of your application unpredictable. It can also introduce synchronization issues if the data changes. Apart from that, if you have one table per page you could apply above logic for each page/table in the session.

Comment: Application_BeginRequest fire on each postback, is not what I need. 
Maybe is better to call datatable variable with same session variable for different pages, so memory not increase much. I need this datatable for gridview order or paging event, and others... data not change in real time. So I call database, set this table in session and use it for next usage on same page.

Comment: but if there is a method to free all variable session on each page change, I'm not need to change all my application...

Comment: @tulkas85: No, there is no such method or event on server. You can only recognize when the user requests a page, not when he "leaves" it since he could simply close his browser.