# Check if user leaves page with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I need to clear some Session data that is stored in it if user are redirected to some page.

I found this post where i can see possible solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/20283726/3917754

But here is one problem - i must enter page Name, according to answer. So entering all page names i don't think is good solution.

Has anybody some ideas how to check if user leaves page to delete session. It must be server side code.

Comment: you can use the function on `onpageshow` . Reference  can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onpageshow.asp)

Comment: you can use Page_Unload event to clear session variables when user leaves page

Comment: @Sandeep, Does `Page_Unload` fire every time when i refresh page?

Comment: Each time when you navigate to new page, why don't you clear the session state of previous page in page_load event.see second answer of the link provided by you.

Comment: @demo yes Page_unload will not work for your scenario because it wil fire always. you have to use jquery onbeforeunload event

Answer (score 1):

You can also do like this:

On each page, define the following script code (or define it in the master page):

```
   window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;

            function confirmExit() {
                var url = '<%: ResolveUrl("~/DeleteSessionAjaxHandler.ashx") %>'
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: "POST",
                    async: false,
                    data: {},
                    success: function(data) {}
                });
            }
```

Create the `DeleteSessionAjaxHandler.ashx` handler and inside delete the session.

```
public class DeletedSessionAjaxHandler: IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
    {
        public override void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            //Session delete code
        }
    }
```

Comment: That js will fire every time when you go to another page.